# Migration to Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7

Currently i am using VS2008, XP Service pack 3 and DotNet framework 2 to develop desktop applications. If i would like to run those applications in Windows 7 (32bit), what else i need to do?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Regards
SKPaul

Comment: It should not be a problem to install VS2008 or .NET 2 on Windows 7 (32bit).

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. Install .NET 4.0 FW, launch application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP Service Pack should support the latest DotNet Framework, so you can test to see if your application still run. If the do, you can migrate to Win7 32bit safely. But I'd advice you take caution and also backup if necessary.